# MYSQL split strings and insert the single words in database

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a MYSQL database with 800.000 rows. Now i want to know: how can i split strings and insert the single words in database?

I.E.

I have this string: "how to use windows 7"

I want to split this string and than insert "how", "to", "use", "windows", "7" in that same table where the string is contained. This must be done for all the 800.000 rows automatically.

I'm developing in java and sql (sqldeveloper).

Ok. I'm adding more informations to be more explicit. This is the definition for my table.

```
CREATE TABLE phrase
(
name VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL default '',
category VARCHAR(60) default '',
PRIMARY KEY(name, category)
);
```

The strings i want to split are "name". So, every single word (from the splitting) will be inserted in "phrase" table.

Comment: What language are using invoking the SQL in? I would probably suggest making use of a construct in that.

Comment: Added more informations in question.

Comment: *Why* are you trying to do this?  Sounds like a fulltext indexing strategy may be all that you need...

Comment: Insert **where**? Into separate fields?

Comment: I'm trying a different version for a text classifier algorithm and i need to do so.

Comment: "A text classifier algorithm"?  Please elaborate.  What is the business requirement, exactly?  I fear this is an incarnation of the [X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this (untested):

```
 String yourQuery = "SELECT * FROM phrases WHERE name = 'how to use windows 7'";
 PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(yourQuery); 
 statement.setMaxRows(1); 
 ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

 String[] arr = null;
 String name;
 while (rs.next()) {
   name = rs.getString(1); // Where 1 is column number.
 }

 arr = name.split(" "); // Split at space 
 // (e.g. "how to use windows 7" becomes "how", "to", "use", "windows", "7"
 System.out.println(arr[2]); // Output "use"
 String combined = Arrays.toString(arr); // "how, to, use, windows, 7"

 yourQuery = "UPDATE phrases SET name = '" + combined + "' WHERE COLUMN = how to use windows 7;"
 statement = connection.prepareStatement(updateStatement);
 int rowsAffected = statement.executeStatement();
```

I based some of the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667913/how-to-get-only-the-first-row-from-a-java-sql-resultset) and some others on here. That would of course be to replace for one row. You would loop and/or modify your SQL statements as appropriate to suit your needs. Also you should sanitize your SQL to prevent injection vectors; but this is just joined here for simplicity.